# Don't know whats going wrong while training dataset. Keras Model Fit

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have just started using Keras and was trying to train a model using Keras deep learning kit. Works till the epochs are runned but crashes just after it.

```
    np.random.seed(1778)  # for reproducibility
    need_normalise=True
    need_validataion=True
    nb_epoch=2#8

    #Creating model 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(dims,)))
    model.add(PReLU())
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    opt=Adadelta(lr=1,decay=0.995,epsilon=1e-5)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
    auc_scores=[]
    best_score=-1
    best_model=None
    print('Training model...')

    if need_validataion:
        for i in range(nb_epoch):
        #early_stopping=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=0, verbose=1)
        #model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,batch_size=256,validation_split=0.01,callbacks=[early_stopping])
            model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=2,batch_size=256,validation_split=0.15)
            y_pre = model.predict_proba(X_valid)
            scores = roc_auc_score(y_valid,y_pre)
            auc_scores.append(scores)
            print (i,scores)
            if scores>best_score:
                best_score=scores
                best_model=model
        plt.plot(auc_scores)
        plt.show()
    else:
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=256)
   y_pre = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
   print roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pre)
```

Error Recieved:
I have pasted it over here. Please have a look at it.
http://pastebin.com/dSw9ckkk

Comment: could you try printing y_valid and y_pre before calculating scores? And tell me what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two classes, a positive class and a negative class, so that the positive class labels are 1 minus the negative class labels.  In that case, you can discard the negative class labels and make it a single-class problem:

```
model.add(Dense(1), activation='sigmoid')  # instead of Dense(nb_classes) and Activation('softmax')
```

Alternatively, you can still train the model on both classes and just use the positive class in the AUC calculation:

```
roc_auc_score(y_test[:, 1],y_pre[:, 1])
```